# Probable error in the proof of the remainder theorem in my grade 10 book

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

The following is given in my book as a proof of the remainder theorem:

> If $p(x)$ is the dividened, $q(x)$ is the quotient, $r(x)$ is the remainder and $(x-a)$ is the divisor, then:
> $$p(x) = q(x)(x-a) + r(x)$$
> If $x=a$,
> $$\implies p(a) = q(a)(0) + r(a)$$
> Hence, $$r(a) = p(a) \tag{i} $$
> Therefore,$$ p(x) = q(x)(x-a) + p(a) \tag{ii}$$
> Hence, we can say $p(a)$ is the remainder.

Isn't it wrong? In the last equation $(ii)$, I assume they have tried to substitute the value of $r(a)$ from equation $(i)$, but that makes equation $(ii)$ before the substitution

$$p(x) = q(x)(x-a) + r(a)$$

But that is wrong right? The correct equation should be

$$p(x) = q(x)(x-a) + r(x)$$

and I don't think $r(x)\neq(a)$.

I think the problem can be avoided easily by *not* using a function of $x$ in the first place and just using a variable like $c$(suppose), where $p(a)$ will be proved equal to $c$, and hence the theorem will also be satisfied and proved.

I am still in grade $10$, hence I might be wrong in some aspects, please go easy on me :)

Comment: Welcome to MathExcange. Please notice the MathJax grammar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If  $p(x)$ and $t(x)$ are two polynomials then there exist two polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$, such that
$$p(x)=q(x)t(x)+r(x), \; \text{deg}(r)<\text{deg}(t)$$
Note that if the divisor $t$ is $x-a$, a polynomial of degree $1$, the remainder $r$ is a polynomial of degree $\le 0$, this means it is a constant. So $r(x)=r(a)$ for this special case and therefore
$$p(x) = q(x)(x-a) + p(a)$$

So if $a$ is a zero of the polynomial, that means that  $p(a)=0$, then
$$p(x)=q(x)(x-a)$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130863/discussion-on-answer-by-miracle173-probable-error-in-the-proof-of-the-remainder).